# Upgrade ELK on docker from 7.10 to 7.17

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, elastic-stack

Need to upgrade Elasticsearch , Kibana installed with docker compose as a 3 node cluster on linux from 7.10 to 7.17
[This document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/targz.html) shares other methods but not containers installed/started with docker compose - swarm.
Is their a step by step documentation for the same?

Comment: Wont changing the image be enough for docker compose ?

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar You mean, just change the version number in compose or .env file and no other changes are needed?

Comment: this is what I feel but i am not very sure. Let me know if you found something else that needs to be changed

Comment: Steps followed gives error as below. Steps: docker-compose stop -> stop the containers->Modify to elasticsearch:7.17.6, and finally start the containers again &  docker-compose up. Error: "Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.17.6
Creating es03 ... error
Creating es01 ...
Creating kib01 ...
Creating es02 ...
Creating es02 ... error

ERROR: for es02 Cannot create container for service es02: Conflict. The container name "/es02" is already in use by container "". You have to remove (or rename) that contaiCreating kib01 ... error
Same error for all nodes

Comment: Is your old pods still up ?? I feel you will either need to rename or else u need to bring down your existing pod. Is this a production elk cluster ? Also your Kibana and elastic image must be of the same version. Hope u have updated both ? I have tried to implement this on local I had 7.10 already being used and I have updated to 7.17.6 and its working fine for me

Comment: Do let me know if my answer has helped you or not. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have upgraded from my elastic from 7.10 to 7.17.6 I have not faced any issues. I have just used docker compose in this scenario. In your case can you try to rename your elastic search it seems that's your older elastic container is still up and its conflicting the name? If this is not a production setup let me know we could try few more things as well.

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.6
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.17.6
    container_name: kib01
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://es01:9200"]'
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: The  docker containers are stopped  but still get the error. Where you can be reached at please. It is non- prod. boodlefin at gmail

Comment: Can you paste the new error ?